# Foreign key Mismatch When Inserting Data - Android Studio SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-sqlite

I am trying to insert values into a database where the primary key references another table. Since the referenced table has all the possible values that can be inserted into the new table, there shouldn't be foreign key mismatch. Maybe you guys will see it where I don't.

```
package com.example.guviolinapp

import android.content.ContentValues
import android.content.Context
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper

class DBHelper(context: Context) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1) {

    private lateinit var db: SQLiteDatabase

    companion object{
        //Companion object that holds the name of everything in the database
        private val DATABASE_NAME = "violininfo.db"
        private val GAME_TABLE = "game_table"
        private val COL_GAME_NUMBER = "game_number"
        private val COL_GAME_SCORE = "game_score"
        private val SCORE_TABLE = "score_table"
        private val COL_SCORE_LEVEL = "quiz_level"
        private val COL_QUIZ_SCORE = "quiz_score"
        private val QUESTION_TABLE = "questions_table"
        private val COL_QUIZ_LEVEL = "quiz_level"
        private val COL_QUESTION_NUM = "question_number"
        private val COL_QUIZ_QUESTION = "quiz_questions"
        private val COL_QUIZ_OPTION_ONE = "quiz_options_one"
        private val COL_QUIZ_OPTION_TWO = "quiz_options_two"
        private val COL_QUIZ_OPTION_THREE = "quiz_options_three"
        private val COL_QUIZ_OPTION_FOUR = "quiz_options_four"
        private val COL_QUIZ_ANSWER = "quiz_answer"
    }

    //On create of the Application creating the actual database in the device
    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
        this.db = db

        //Variable that holds the SQL query to create the table
        val CREATE_GAME_TABLE =
                "CREATE TABLE ${GAME_TABLE}" +
                "($COL_GAME_NUMBER INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                "$COL_GAME_SCORE INTEGER" +
                ")"
        //Variable that holds the SQL query to create the table
        val CREATE_QUESTION_TABLE =
                "CREATE TABLE ${QUESTION_TABLE}" +
                "($COL_QUIZ_LEVEL INTEGER, " +
                "$COL_QUESTION_NUM INTEGER, " +
                "$COL_QUIZ_QUESTION TEXT, " +
                "$COL_QUIZ_OPTION_ONE TEXT, " +
                "$COL_QUIZ_OPTION_TWO TEXT, " +
                "$COL_QUIZ_OPTION_THREE TEXT, " +
                "$COL_QUIZ_OPTION_FOUR TEXT, " +
                "$COL_QUIZ_ANSWER INTEGER, " +
                "PRIMARY KEY ($COL_QUIZ_LEVEL, $COL_QUESTION_NUM)" +
                ")"
        //Variable that holds the SQL query to create the table
        val CREATE_SCORE_TABLE =
                "CREATE TABLE ${SCORE_TABLE}" +
                "($COL_SCORE_LEVEL INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                "$COL_QUIZ_SCORE INTEGER, " +
                "FOREIGN KEY ($COL_SCORE_LEVEL) REFERENCES $QUESTION_TABLE($COL_QUIZ_LEVEL) ON DELETE CASCADE" +
                ")"

        //Functions that execute the sql script. The first one prevents null in the db
        db.execSQL(CREATE_QUESTION_TABLE)
        db.execSQL(CREATE_GAME_TABLE)
        db.execSQL(CREATE_SCORE_TABLE)
        fillQuestionsTable()
    }

    //Function that drops the database and remakes it for when the database is updated. It can be done two ways.
    //The app can be deleted, or the version can be increased
    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
        val DROP_SCORE_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $SCORE_TABLE"
        val DROP_GAME_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $GAME_TABLE"
        val DROP_QUESTION_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $QUESTION_TABLE"

        db.execSQL(DROP_SCORE_TABLE)
        db.execSQL(DROP_GAME_TABLE)
        db.execSQL(DROP_QUESTION_TABLE)
        onCreate(db)
    }

    override fun onConfigure(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
        super.onConfigure(db)
        db.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(true)
    }


    //Function to insert values into the Score table
    fun insertScoreTable(quizLevel: Int, quizScore: Int): Boolean? {
        //Initializing the db
        val db = this.writableDatabase
        //Function to insert values that will be inserted into the database
        val cv = ContentValues()
        //Inserting the values with a specific identifier in which the value needs to be inserted
        cv.put(COL_SCORE_LEVEL, quizLevel)
        cv.put(COL_QUIZ_SCORE, quizScore)
        //Executing the actual insert database
        val res = db.insert(SCORE_TABLE, null, cv)
        return !res.equals(-1)
    }

    //Function to insert values into the Game table
    fun insertGameTable(gameNum: Int, gameScore: Int): Boolean? {
        //Initializing the db
        val db = this.writableDatabase
        //Function to insert values that will be inserted into the database
        val cv = ContentValues()
        //Inserting the values with a specific identifier in which the value needs to be inserted
        cv.put(COL_GAME_NUMBER, gameNum)
        cv.put(COL_GAME_SCORE, gameScore)
        //Executing the actual insert database
        val res = db.insert(GAME_TABLE, null, cv)
        return !res.equals(-1)
    }

    //Function to insert values into the Questions table
    private fun insertQuestionsTable(questionTable: QuestionsTable): Boolean? {
        //Function to insert values that will be inserted into the database
        val cv = ContentValues()
        //Inserting the values with a specific identifier in which the value needs to be inserted
        cv.put(COL_QUIZ_LEVEL, questionTable.quiz_level)
        cv.put(COL_QUESTION_NUM, questionTable.question_number)
        cv.put(COL_QUIZ_QUESTION, questionTable.quiz_questions)
        cv.put(COL_QUIZ_OPTION_ONE, questionTable.quiz_option_one)
        cv.put(COL_QUIZ_OPTION_TWO, questionTable.quiz_option_two)
        cv.put(COL_QUIZ_OPTION_THREE, questionTable.quiz_option_three)
        cv.put(COL_QUIZ_OPTION_FOUR, questionTable.quiz_option_four)
        cv.put(COL_QUIZ_ANSWER, questionTable.quiz_answer)
        //Executing the actual insert database
        val res = db.insert(QUESTION_TABLE, null, cv)
        return !res.equals(-1)
    }

    //Function to insert all the questions into the database
    private fun fillQuestionsTable() {
        //Variable with the data class holding the values for each question
        val l1q1 = QuestionsTable(1, 1, "What note is this?", "Minim",
            "Semibreve", "Crochet", "Quaver", 4)
        //Calling the insertQuestionsTable to insert the question
        insertQuestionsTable(l1q1)

        val l1q2 = QuestionsTable(1, 2, "What note is this?", "Quaver",
            "Minim", "Crochet", "Semibreve", 3)
        insertQuestionsTable(l1q2)

        val l1q3 = QuestionsTable(1, 3, "What rest is this?", "Whole",
            "Eighth", "Half", "Quarter", 2)
        insertQuestionsTable(l1q3)

        val l1q4 = QuestionsTable(1, 4, "What rest is this?", "Quarter",
            "Eighth", "Whole", "Half", 1)
        insertQuestionsTable(l1q4)

        val l1q5 = QuestionsTable(1, 5, "What rest is this?", "Whole",
        "Eighth", "Quarter", "Half", 1)
        insertQuestionsTable(l1q5)

        val l1q6 = QuestionsTable(1, 6, "What rest is this?", "Quarter",
            "Eighth", "Whole", "Half", 4)
        insertQuestionsTable(l1q6)

        val l1q7 = QuestionsTable(1, 7, "What note is this?", "Minim",
            "Quaver", "Semibreve", "Crochet", 1)
        insertQuestionsTable(l1q7)

        val l1q8 = QuestionsTable(1, 8, "What note is this?", "Quaver",
            "Semibreve", "Crochet", "Minim", 2)
        insertQuestionsTable(l1q8)

        val l1q9 = QuestionsTable(1, 9, "How many beats in this rest?", "Half Beat",
            "One Beat", "Two Beats", "Four Beats", 3)
        insertQuestionsTable(l1q9)

        val l1q10 = QuestionsTable(1, 10, "How many beats in this rest?", "Four Beats",
            "One Beat", "Two Beats", "Half Beat", 4)
        insertQuestionsTable(l1q10)

        val l1q11 = QuestionsTable(1, 11, "How many beats in this rest?", "One Beat",
            "Half Beat", "Two Beats", "Four Beats", 4)
        insertQuestionsTable(l1q11)

        val l1q12 = QuestionsTable(1, 12, "How many beats in this note?", "Four Beats",
            "One Beat", "Half Beat", "Two Beats", 2)
        insertQuestionsTable(l1q12)

        val l1q13 = QuestionsTable(1, 13, "How many beats in this rest?", "Two Beats",
            "One Beat", "Four Beats", "Half Beat", 2)
        insertQuestionsTable(l1q13)

        val l1q14 = QuestionsTable(1, 14, "How many beats in this note?", "Two Beats",
            "Half Beat", "Four Beats", "One Beat", 3)
        insertQuestionsTable(l1q14)

        val l1q15 = QuestionsTable(1, 15, "How many beats in this note?", "One Beat",
            "Four Beats", "Half Beat", "Two Beats", 3)
        insertQuestionsTable(l1q15)

        val l2q1 = QuestionsTable(2, 1, "What string is this?", "D",
            "A", "G", "E", 1)
        insertQuestionsTable(l2q1)

        val l2q2 = QuestionsTable(2, 2, "What note is this?", "F sharp",
            "E", "G sharp", "A", 1)
        insertQuestionsTable(l2q2)

        val l2q3 = QuestionsTable(2, 3, "What note is this?", "G",
            "B", "A", "C", 2)
        insertQuestionsTable(l2q3)

        val l2q4 = QuestionsTable(2, 4, "What note is this?", "E",
            "F sharp", "A", "G sharp", 4)
        insertQuestionsTable(l2q4)

        val l2q5 = QuestionsTable(2, 5, "What note is this?", "G",
            "A", "B", "C", 4)
        insertQuestionsTable(l2q5)

        val l2q6 = QuestionsTable(2, 6, "What string is this?", "A",
            "D", "E", "G", 3)
        insertQuestionsTable(l2q6)

        val l2q7 = QuestionsTable(2, 7, "What note is this?", "B",
            "A", "C", "G", 2)
        insertQuestionsTable(l2q7)

        val l2q8 = QuestionsTable(2, 8, "What note is this?", "E",
            "D", "G", "F sharp", 4)
        insertQuestionsTable(l2q8)

        val l2q9 = QuestionsTable(2, 9, "What note is this?", "A",
            "B", "C sharp", "D", 4)
        insertQuestionsTable(l2q9)

        val l2q10 = QuestionsTable(2, 10, "What note is this?", "F sharp",
            "D", "E", "G", 3)
        insertQuestionsTable(l2q10)

        val l2q11 = QuestionsTable(2, 11, "What note is this?", "A",
            "B", "C sharp", "D", 2)
        insertQuestionsTable(l2q11)

        val l2q12 = QuestionsTable(2, 12, "What string is this?", "D",
            "G", "E", "A", 4)
        insertQuestionsTable(l2q12)

        val l2q13 = QuestionsTable(2, 13, "What note is this?", "C sharp",
            "D", "B", "A", 1)
        insertQuestionsTable(l2q13)

        val l2q14 = QuestionsTable(2, 14, "What note is this?", "E",
            "G", "F sharp", "D", 2)
        insertQuestionsTable(l2q14)

        val l2q15 = QuestionsTable(2, 15, "What string is this?", "A",
            "D", "G", "E", 3)
        insertQuestionsTable(l2q15)

        val l3q1 = QuestionsTable(3, 1, "What is this called?", "Treble Clef",
            "Tie", "Stave", "Flat", 3)
        insertQuestionsTable(l3q1)

        val l3q2 = QuestionsTable(3, 2, "What is this called?", "Stave",
            "Bass Clef", "Sharp", "Treble Clef", 3)
        insertQuestionsTable(l3q2)

        val l3q3 = QuestionsTable(3, 3, "What is this called?", "Bar",
            "Stave", "Sharp", "Bass Clef", 1)
        insertQuestionsTable(l3q3)

        val l3q4 = QuestionsTable(3, 4, "What is this called?", "Time Signature",
            "Treble Clef", "Natural", "Bass Clef", 2)
        insertQuestionsTable(l3q4)

        val l3q5 = QuestionsTable(3, 5, "What is this called?", "Bar",
            "Key Signature", "Sharp", "Tie", 2)
        insertQuestionsTable(l3q5)

        val l3q6 = QuestionsTable(3, 6, "What is this called?", "Treble Clef",
            "Key Signature", "Bar", "Tie", 4)
        insertQuestionsTable(l3q6)

        val l3q7 = QuestionsTable(3, 7, "What is this called?", "Flat",
            "Sharp", "Bar", "Natural", 1)
        insertQuestionsTable(l3q7)

        val l3q8 = QuestionsTable(3, 8, "What is this called?", "Treble Clef",
            "Flat", "Sharp", "Bass Clef", 4)
        insertQuestionsTable(l3q8)

        val l3q9 = QuestionsTable(3, 9, "What is this called?", "Sharp",
            "Time Signature", "Flat", "Tie", 2)
        insertQuestionsTable(l3q9)

        val l3q10 = QuestionsTable(3, 10, "What is this called?", "Bass Clef",
            "Bar", "Natural", "Sharp", 3)
        insertQuestionsTable(l3q10)

        val l3q11 = QuestionsTable(3, 11, "What is this called?", "Decrescendo",
            "Accent", "Forte", "Crescendo", 1)
        insertQuestionsTable(l3q11)

        val l3q12 = QuestionsTable(3, 12, "What is this called?", "Decrescendo",
            "Forte", "Accent", "Piano", 4)
        insertQuestionsTable(l3q12)

        val l3q13 = QuestionsTable(3, 13, "What is this called?", "Forte",
            "Accent", "Crescendo", "Decrescendo", 1)
        insertQuestionsTable(l3q13)

        val l3q14 = QuestionsTable(3, 14, "What is this called?", "Decrescendo",
            "Accent", "Crescendo", "Forte", 2)
        insertQuestionsTable(l3q14)

        val l3q15 = QuestionsTable(3, 15, "What is this called?", "Forte",
            "Piano", "Accent", "Crescendo", 4)
        insertQuestionsTable(l3q15)


    }

    //Function get the questions back from the database.
    fun getLevelQuestions(quizLevel: Int): ArrayList<QuestionsTable> {
        //Initializing db
        val db = this.readableDatabase
        //Selection variable that holds the attribute we need
        val selection = "$COL_QUIZ_LEVEL = ? "
        //Argument variable that holds which row we need
        val selectionArgs = arrayOf(quizLevel.toString())
        //Creating the ArrayList that holds the questions retrieved from the database
        val rv = ArrayList<QuestionsTable>()
        //Query that gets the values from the database
        val csr = db.query(QUESTION_TABLE,null /* ALL columns */,selection,selectionArgs,null,null,null)

        //While loop that insert the values into the array list while there is a next value
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            //Adding values to the array list
            rv.add(
                //Inserting the values into the data class
                QuestionsTable(
                    //Getting the actual values from the query
                    csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_QUIZ_LEVEL)),
                    csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_QUESTION_NUM)),
                    csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_QUIZ_QUESTION)),
                    csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_QUIZ_OPTION_ONE)),
                    csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_QUIZ_OPTION_TWO)),
                    csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_QUIZ_OPTION_THREE)),
                    csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_QUIZ_OPTION_FOUR)),
                    csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_QUIZ_ANSWER))
                )
            )

        }

        //Closing the database query
        csr.close()
        //Returning the ArrayList
        return rv
    }

    //Function get the scores back from the database.
    fun getAllScores(): ArrayList<ScoreTable> {
        val db = this.readableDatabase
        //Creating the ArrayList that holds the questions retrieved from the database
        val rv = ArrayList<ScoreTable>()
        //While loop that insert the values into the array list while there is a next value
        val csr = db.query(SCORE_TABLE,null /* ALL columns */,null,null,null,null,null)

        //While loop that insert the values into the array list while there is a next value
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            //Adding values to the array list
            rv.add(
                //Inserting the values into the data class
                ScoreTable(
                    //Getting the actual values from the query
                    csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_SCORE_LEVEL)),
                    csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_QUIZ_SCORE))
                )
            )
        }

        //Closing the database query
        csr.close()
        //Returning the ArrayList
        return rv
    }

    //Function get the Game scores back from the database.
    fun getAllGameScores(): ArrayList<GameTable> {
        val db = this.readableDatabase
        //Creating the ArrayList that holds the questions retrieved from the database
        val rv = ArrayList<GameTable>()
        //While loop that insert the values into the array list while there is a next value
        val csr = db.query(GAME_TABLE,null /* ALL columns */,null,null,null,null,null)

        //While loop that insert the values into the array list while there is a next value
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            //Adding values to the array list
            rv.add(
                //Inserting the values into the data class
                GameTable(
                    //Getting the actual values from the query
                    csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_GAME_NUMBER)),
                    csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_GAME_SCORE))
                )
            )
        }

        //Closing the database query
        csr.close()
        //Returning the ArrayList
        return rv
    }
}
```

This is the class that creates the database and where the insert function is made. Next is the error code that also holds the info that would cause the foreign key mismatch

```
2020-08-06 11:10:44.662 24432-24432/com.example.guviolinapp E/SQLiteLog: (1) foreign key mismatch - "score_table" referencing "questions_table"
2020-08-06 11:10:44.664 24432-24432/com.example.guviolinapp E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting quiz_score=3 quiz_level=1
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: foreign key mismatch - "score_table" referencing "questions_table" (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO score_table(quiz_score,quiz_level) VALUES (?,?)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1472)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1343)
        at com.example.guviolinapp.DBHelper.insertScoreTable(DBHelper.kt:99)
        at com.example.guviolinapp.ResultActivity.onCreate(ResultActivity.kt:31)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the `CREATE` statement of the table `score_table`:

```
CREATE TABLE score_table(
  quiz_level INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  quiz_score INTEGER, 
  FOREIGN KEY (quiz_level) REFERENCES questions_table(quiz_level) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

where you have defined that the column `quiz_level` references the column `quiz_level` of the table `questions_table`.

Also in the method `onConfigure()` you have:

```
db.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(true)
```

which enables foreign key constraints for the database.

This means that any value in the column `quiz_level` of the table `score_table` must exist in the column `quiz_level` of the table `questions_table`.

What this error says is that you tried to insert  a new row in the table `score_table` with a value in `quiz_level` that does not exist in `questions_table`.

So before you insert this row you must insert a row in `questions_table` with the same `quiz_level`.

Also SQLite requires that the referenced column `quiz_level` in `questions_table` is either the `PRIMARY KEY` of the table or it should have a `UNIQUE INDEX` or `UNIQUE constraint`, (find more here: [SQLite Foreign Key Support](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html)) but none of this is true in the definition of the table `questions_table`.

Comment: I checked the database. There is a quiz level that matches the quiz level I put into the score table. So that isn't the problem